# pm2 about the web interface on port 9615 data

Tags: node.js, pm2

In the pm2 web interface, I can have more data than with the monitoring, but it provides data such as the bank user, the ip, the password etc. (data from ecosystem.config.js). Would you like to restrict access to the web interface for a given domain, or is there some other way to protect the same domain?

Comment: I guess all of this depends on what are you trying to do. So what is that you are after?

Comment: I have a panel being monitored by the same wanted to leave my bank data etc. protected